# Bash `set -x` only for the duration of a function

Tags: bash

I have a function that runs several commands and each of them take awhile to finish. I added `set -x` at the beginning so that I can see exactly which command is executing while it's running. Then at the end I disable it with `set +x`.

```
function toolong() {
  set -x;
  takes_a_long_time &&\
  takes_also_a_long_time &&\ # <=== Hangs here, for example
  takes_more time
  set +x;
}
```

My problem is that sometimes I need to kill my process if one of the functions hangs or is taking too long. When that happens i'm left with a bunch of crap in my shell as `set +x` never got called.

Is there a way to limit the scope of `set -x` only to the duration of a specific function or otherwise guarantee that `set +x` always gets called?

Comment: Which process do you kill? Is it `takes_also_a_long_time` or is it the calling script?

Comment: You do not need "\" after `&&`, and use `NAME()` instead of `function NAME()`.

Comment: > Which process do you kill? 

Mostly hitting CTRL+C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to affect current execution environment, just run it all in a subshell.

```
toolong() {
  (
     set -x;
     takes_a_long_time &&
     takes_also_a_long_time &&
     takes_more time
  )
}
```

Or shorter you can:

```
toolong() (
  set -x;
  takes_a_long_time &&
  takes_also_a_long_time &&
  takes_more time
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `trap` for cleaning up when the `toolong` function is interrupted:

```bash
trap '[[ " ${FUNCNAME[*]} " == *\ toolong\ * ]] && set +x' INT
```

or just every-time that a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is typed:

```bash
trap 'set +x' INT
```